# How to auto refresh table content in sql from .txt when .txt changed?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in Database like dbo.foo and have stored procedure which one  reads data to dbo.foo from foo.txt. Until this point everything is working fine. Now, I need an automatism, which starts stored procedure when foo.txt has changed (saved).

foo.txt is coming from a client in the network with 'robocopy'. This works as well. I created a .bat file in server with SQLCMD for 'exec' the stored procedure. It also works on server, but I cannot run it from client.

The SQLCMD is just a possible way, not necessary to follow this path. The greatest solution would be a 'trigger' or something in MsSql server based on foo.txt changing.

Comment: create job and run it often as you wish.

Comment: After the Robocopy step, call `BCP` to push the text file into a table then call `SQLCMD` to run a stored procedure to merge it where it has to go. Trigger it from your existing batch file.

Comment: You could set up an SSIS task that has a WMI Event Watcher task (on the file), which continuously runs.

Comment: If you really need immediate execution, you could create a windows service that watches the file for changes and executes the stored procedure. If you don’t need to handle immediate change to the file, you could run a scheduled task or an agent job on a schedule that checks if the file has changed.

Comment: Ok, so there's no own solution in Ms Sql Server. :( How can I create windows service for watching and executing? THX.